# Cross-correlation in time or frequency domain (FPGA)

Tags: fpga, fft

I need to compute the complex cross-correlation between two signals a and b and the take only the maximum value of the cross-correlation, regardless of the lag time where this occurs. I can do it either in time domain or in frequency domain. This needs to be later incorporated in a FPGA, so I want to be efficient.

An alternative is to go to frequency domain correlation, but I would need to do

max(IFFT(FFT(a)*conj(FFT(b))))
which is probably computationally costly.

Is there a way to avoid going back and forth twice to the frequency and time domain?

Comment: What kind of signals? Because I think you need "some" memory to do that.

Comment: These are complex signals that have been digitized by an ADC